# I am trying to copy the format of first row to rest of the rows in my range

Tags: excel, vba

I have created 2 funcs, but both give `Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined` error. Can you tell me what is the error here.

```
Sub test()
    Dim RowCount, ColumnCount As Integer
    Dim sRangeSt, sRangeEn, tRangeSt, tRangeEn As String
    Dim tmpRange As Range

        RowCount = Range("main").Rows.Count
        ColumnCount = Range("main").Columns.Count

        'prepare range start and end cell-addresses
        sRangeSt = Range("main").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).Address
        sRangeEn = Range("main").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).Address
        tRangeSt = Range("main").End(xlToLeft).Offset(2, 0).Address
        tRangeEn = Range("main").End(xlToLeft).Offset(RowCount - 1, ColumnCount - 1).Address

        'Perform style copy
        Range(sRangeSt & ":" & sRangeEn).Copy
        'Worksheets("Report").Select
        Worksheets("Report").Range(tRangeSt & ":" & tRangeEn).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End Sub


Sub test2()
    Dim sRangeSt, sRangeEn, tRangeSt, tRangeEn As String
    sRangeSt = Range("main").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).Address
    sRangeEn = Range("main").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).Address

    'Perform style copy
    Range(sRangeSt & ":" & sRangeEn).Copy

    For Each Row In Range("main").Rows
        Range(Row.Address).PasteSpecial xmlPasteFormts
    Next Row
End Sub
```

First block gives error at the last line. I tried by reducing the row-count of target rows, and it ran fine for excel range 4096 rows, but failed for ranges of greater row-count with the above error.

Comment: What is the address stored in `main`?

Comment: @L42 - Address is '=Report!$A$14:$P$12458', and scope is 'workbook'.

Comment: I tried your code and it is working. maybe you should improve your variable declarations so you would always get the result you want. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your range is not fully qualified. Just by enclosing the code in `With End With` will not qualify the range. Add a `.` (DOT) before every range. For example

```
With Sheets("Report")
    RowCount = Range("main").Rows.Count
    ColumnCount = Range("main").Columns.Count
```

becomes

```
With Sheets("Report")
    RowCount = .Range("main").Rows.Count
    ColumnCount = .Range("main").Columns.Count
```

Similarly for the rest

Comment: Thanks for your response - Siddharta. Actually, I `m not using 'With - EndWith' this block here. as 'main' is a workbook-scoped range. We can ignore that.. I`l update my code. The error is occuring in the last line... It pastes fine till 4096 rows, but in the next row it gives ' Application-defined or object-defined error'.